# Relation maximal or minimal.

Tags: relations

Consider the set $\{2,3,4\}$ and define partial ordering if $a$ divides $b$. 
Element 3 is not related to anybody else therefore after Hasse Diagram element 3 is maximal or minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, 3 is *both* minimal and maximal. 2 is minimal;  4 is maximal.
Exercise.  What are the maximal chains and maximal antichains?